# How to resize div based on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a landing page with some interesting idea of menu. It is built with custom made hexagons. I want to make these hexacgons to fill all screen based on screen resolution. Basically i want to make them adapt to screen with no need to scroll. 
my website: http://new.glstudios.lv/

```
<div class='grid'>
<div onclick="location.href='';" id="smallbox" ; class='grid--item'>
  <div class='img' style='background-image: url();'></div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Snowy Hills</h2>
      <div class='desc'>Photo by Ales Krivec</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid--item'>
    <div class='img' style='background-image: url();'></div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Bear</h2>
      <div class='desc'>Photo by Thomas Lefebvre</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid--item'>
    <div class='img' style='background-image: url();'></div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Owl</h2>
      <div class='desc'>Photo by photostockeditor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid--item'>
    <div class='img' style='background-image: url();'></div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Horse</h2>
      <div class='desc'>Photo by Annie Spratt</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid--item'>
    <div class='img' style='background-image: url();'></div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Ice & Penguin</h2>
      <div class='desc'>Photo by Teodor Bjerrang</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid--item'>
    <div class='img' style='background-image: url( );'></div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Pile of Logs</h2>
      <div class='desc'>Photo by Ales Krivec</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid--item'>
    <div class='img' style='background-image: url( );'></div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Winter Tree</h2>
      <div class='desc'>Photo by Mikael Kristenson</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS.

```
#smallbox {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.x-main.full {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    background:black;
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arapey:400italic);
body {
  background: white;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  min-width: 1200px;
}

.grid {
  padding: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.grid--item {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
}
.grid--item:before {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 112.5%;
  content: '';
}
.grid--item:nth-child(1), .grid--item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.grid--item:nth-child(7n - 1), .grid--item:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 185px;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
}
.img:before, .img:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.img:before {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.25);
}
.img:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  will-change: transform;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Arapey';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 56px;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color:white;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.03em;
  background: turquoise;
  content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.desc {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  font-family: 'ATC Overlook';
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: turquoise;
}

.grid--item:hover .img:before,
.grid--item:hover .img:after,
.grid--item:hover .container {
  opacity: 1;
}
.grid--item:hover .container {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can actually help you.

Comment: I've done this before... you will need to do a lot of math in Javascript. First you find out how tall and wide your screen is, then you find out which one is the one that limits you (it will differ on portrait vs landscape), and finally decide what the size of each hexagon should be. I did this with triangles and had to brush up on trigonometry to get it done. I wish you good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="test-div"></div>
```

You could do this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#test-div').css('width', $(window).width());
    $('#test-div').css('height', $(window).height());
});
```

But it's very hard to tell without you posting your actual HTML/Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try adding **style="overflow:auto"** after the divider tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you may want to use javascript or jquery to alter the css on resize. 
Something along the lines of:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.container').css('transform','translate(-50%, -50%) scale(dynamicvaluehere);');
});
```

You'll want to calculate your dynamicvaluehere variable based on window height and window width.